# Do I need transit visa to UK, if I have EEA residence permit?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit

*Input*: I have Russian citizenship, but I live in Europe and I have Schengen long-term residence permit(**not permanent residence**). I would like to go to **France** through **UK London Stansted airport**. I will be coming to London at 8 o'clock AM and I have flight from London to France at 10:50 AM. What I have read there is no airside in Stansted airport, so it means, that I will have to go to UK border control.

I have checked if I need visa to UK in [government website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/russia/transit/somewhere_else/yes) and it is written here that I need. **However**, it is also written here, there is possibility to transit **without** visa if:

- you arrive and depart by air(**yes**, I will travel by planes)
- have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive(**yes**, I have)
- have the correct documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country) (**yes**, I have visa to Schengen  zone)

And also I **must have** at least one point from the list in website:

- Have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland (**yes**, I have)

*Question: Do I need really transit visa to UK?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, Stansted has no transit corridor, meaning you have to cross the UK border.

As the information you're referring to confirms, as you have an EEA residence permit, you can cross the UK border without a visa by presenting your passport, filled-out landing card and residence permit card, and stay no longer than 23:59 the next day.

So no, you do **not** need a transit visa.