# Transit visa UK

Tags: transit-visas

This question was asked a few times in the forums (e.g., [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27006/do-i-need-transit-visa-in-london-with-an-eea-residence-permit), [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88211/do-i-need-transit-visa-to-uk-if-i-have-eea-residence-permit)).
I'm an indian citizen traveling from the Oslo, Norway to India via London Heathrow Terminal 5. I've a valid residence permit to live in Norway.

As I understand from this [website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes), I can exit the airport and get to an airport Hotel if:

- you arrive and depart by air (Yes, I've)
- have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive (This is confusing slightly, I'll explain below)
- have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country -- Yes, I'm a citizen).

Is my understanding of the second point correct?  If the first flight is on Monday, then the second one needs to leave the same day (Monday) or before midnight the next day (Tuesday). In my case, I land on Monday evening and leave on Tuesday afternoon. Would that be fine?

One of the following must also apply:

- you have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland
- you have a uniform format category D visa for entry to a country in the EEA or Switzerland

What is the common format residence permit or category D visa?

Comment: Is your residence permit type listed here (page 90 for Norway) https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/system/files/2021-09/handbook-annex_22.pdf#90?

Comment: Yes - could you please let me know if my understanding of the second point is correct?